# kotlinOptions in kotlin multiplatform project

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to use the Android dependency `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.2` to be able to load `ViewModels` in fragments but I am getting an error when trying to use `viewModels()` saying

> Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is
>   being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target'
>   option

Searching that I found that in the `android` section of the `build.gradle` you need to put in the `kotlinOptions`

```
kotlinOptions {jvmTarget = '1.8'}
```

but when building I get an error

> Could not find method kotlinOptions() for arguments

When I do this in a normal Android project it works fine because I assume its part of the `kotlin-android` plugin.

How do I use this in kotlin multiplatform?

Comment: See my post for the actual solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67009242/how-to-configure-kotlin-jvmtarget-in-a-multiplatform-android-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up I my imports were wrong, I needed import

```
import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel
```

then all I had to do was

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel<MyViewModel>()
```